# SDL 1.2 and SDL 2.0 show black screen on MACOS Mojave when rendering OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl, macos-mojave

While working OpenGL code using SDL 1.2 and 2.0 on MAC Mojave, the SDL window is now showing a black screen (It was working perfectly before updating to MACOS Mojave).

I googled a solution for a while  and I didn't find any.

The only thing that **solved** the issue was updating to Mojave 10.14.3 and Xcode 10.1 . I recommend you to do the same

Comment: Are you saying you already solved the problem? If so, rather than saying it in the question, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I was trying to find a question for posting this as a solution.  But I didn't find any thread on this regard. If you see a thread asking this question, please point me in that direction to paste the answer on that thread and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading is not treating the problem, it's just masking the symptoms.

> the SDL window is now showing a black screen

To me this looks like an issue with double buffer configuration and/or use. But it's hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: I'm not talking about downgrading. All the opposite, I'm proposing updating to the latest Mojave and Xcode version.  The issue is fixed in the latest versions of Xcode Build tools (Which require the latest version of MACOS Mojave)